# Plotting error bars in matplotlib that match scatter colours

Tags: python, plot, colors, scatter, errorbar

I've seen quite a few questions along the same vein as this one but they always seem to diverge a little before they answer my question exactly or I can apply them.

I am looking to plot error bars in the same colour scheme as my scatter graph points. If my values were plotted on an x and y axis and I wished them to vary colour with another Z value logarithmically, currently I have:

```
c = np.abs(zVals)
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("plasma")

sc.set_clim(vmin=min(zVals), vmax=max(zVals))

sc = plt.scatter(xVals, yVals, c=c, norm=mplc.LogNorm(), 
s=50, cmap=cmhot, edgecolors='none')

###This section all works fine, it is when I introduce the error bars I struggle

norm = mplc.LogNorm(vmin=min(zVals), vmax=max(zVals)

plt.errorbar(xVals, yVals, yerr = [negyVals,posyVals], c=cmhot(norm(zVals)))
plt.colorbar(sc)


plt.ylim([-10,110])
plt.xlim([1,100])

plt.xscale('log')


plt.show()
```

This results in an error of the form:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg ... length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4
```

I am quite confused with the colour situation in general so any help would be much appreciated at the moment. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is surprisingly hard to do in matplotlib. The only way I've found is to use a for loop, and plot each point individually.

For example

```
plt.figure()

#data
x=np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y=np.cos(x)
y_error=0.2+0.5*np.random.randn(len(x))
z=np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

cm=plt.get_cmap('plasma')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z_values, cmap=cm, zorder=10)


for i, (xval, yval, y_error_val, zval) in enumerate(zip(x, y, y_error, z)):

    #Get the colour from the colourmap
    colour=cm(1.0*zval/np.max(z))
    #(could also just do colour=cm(1.0*i/len(x)) here)
    #(Or Norm(zval) in your case)

    plt.errorbar(xval, yval, yerr=y_error_val, linestyle='', c=colour)

plt.show()
```

which gives [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJqwL.png)

Obviously this won't be very efficient for large numbers of points!

Comment: This is perfect for me as I wasn't using a huge amount of points.

Sadly I've already handed my project in with just some lowered opacity bars and that kinda matched what I wanted, but I'll be using this next time!